# Joining mirrored object causes half of it to disappear

Tags: mesh, mirror

Trying to join my meshes to create a single mesh so it is easier for exporting/ However when I click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to join them all of the mirrored meshes disappear and I am left with half a shape. 
Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

If you are using the mirror-modifier, make sure to 'Apply' the modifier in the 'Modifiers' tab under 'Properties' in 'Object Mode'.

If you have multiple Meshes that are mirrored via the mirror-modifier, first 'Apply' the mirror-modifiers on each, then continue joining the meshes via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

As you joined one mesh to the other your Origin propably went back to the center of the mesh. Make sure you change that. Go and select the edge of your model from which you want the mirror to start, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> and then 4th option. Then exit the Edit Mode and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> and choose the 3rd option, **Origin to 3d Cursor**.

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it was disabling the mirror, duplicating the mesh, and inverting the scale. Then doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to join the meshes.